# Books for Tate's Thesis

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation, harmonic-analysis, class-field-theory

I'm recently reading 'Fourier Analysis on Number Fields ',by Dinakar Ramakrishnan, Robert J. Valenza.The book is aiming to explain Tate's thesis,which is of my current interests.But I've found numbers of mistake in the book,though the conclusions are right,and I'm not very comfortable with the writing style.So is there any relevant book on the same topics for reference?

Comment: How about reading Tate's thesis itself?

Comment: One easy place to find Tate's Thesis in print is Cassels and Frohlich. And it is probably online somewhere too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following text useful:
http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/theses/leahy/thesis.pdf

Comment: It isn't difficult to introduce Tate thesis for $\zeta(s)$ no need for such abstract stuffs, then show how it works with a number field and expect the reader can generalize himself. The difficulty is then to relate it with modular forms.

Comment: Yes,the text adds many details of the original book which is quite useful.